# Python creating object from .txt not working

Tags: object, for-loop, indexing

Trying to read a .txt file then turn its information into an object:

```
class HeaderReader:
    @staticmethod
    def headerFromFile(filePath):
        with open(filePath, 'r') as file:

            headerList = HeaderList()
            headerFile = ''

            for element in range(7):
                headerFile += file.readline()
                tempList= headerFile.rstrip().split('\n')

#tempList= ['Company:', 'Things', 'Day:', '07:11:1987', 'Time:', '15:55', 'Transfers:']

            for splittedEls in tempList:
                header = Header(
                    splittedEls[0],
                    splittedEls[1],
                    splittedEls[2],
                    splittedEls[3],
                    splittedEls[4],
                    splittedEls[5],
                    splittedEls[6]
                )
                headerList.append(header)
            return headerList
```

Works fine until it reachs `splittedEls[4]` which is 'Time:' returning `IndexError: string index out of range` which makes no sense for me. Header class is just a standard 7 paramenters class, will post if needed. Any idea on what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, i think the second loop was just wrong, think this works:

```
class HeaderReader:
    @staticmethod
    def headerFromFile(filePath):
        with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
            headerList = HeaderList()
            headerFile = ''
            for element in range(7):
                headerFile += file.readline()
                tempList = headerFile.rstrip().split('\n')

            header = Header(
                tempList[0],
                tempList[1],
                tempList[2],
                tempList[3],
                tempList[4],
                tempList[5],
                tempList[6]
            )

            return header
```